# Spark - avro data not visible when queried from hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive, databricks

I am creating dataframe using spark avro like

```
dataframe.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save(outputPath)
```

The output path in my case will be like **hdfs path + table_name + partitio**n

The table table_name is already created in hive using AvroSerDe where the LOCATION is set to outputPath.

However the created dataframe is not visible when I do a select * for table_name from hive. What could be issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER Table ADD PARTITION fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that `.save` doesn't update the Hive Metastore, and so the new data isn't visible from your query.

You could try with `dataframe.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).partitionBy("partition").saveAsTable("table_name")` to append data into your table.